# Calculated Column to Get Totals & Percentages

Tags: sharepoint-server, calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

So I have columns set up like so:

```
Entity       Region   Quarters   Year    Month   #ofOps   #ofMisops   %ofMisops
Company A    East     Q1         2020    Jan     1        1           100%
Company A    East     Q1         2020    Feb     3        1           33%
Company A    East     Q1         2020    Mar     3        1           33%
Company B    West     Q1         2020    Jan     1        1           100%
Company B    West     Q1         2020    Feb     1        1           100%
Company B    West     Q1         2020    Mar     1        1           100%
```

What I need is totals of Ops and Misops for each Month for Each entity than each region. Then I need percentages by month and percentages by quarter.
In the diagram above - Company A has 7 Ops and 3 Misops for Q1 which is 2%
In January, there were 2 ops total and 2 misops total which is 100% for the month.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint calculated column does not support calculate multiple items.
You could use view setting(group by,Totals) to get the count of #ofOps and #ofMisops.
[image]
percentages may need to be calculated using code.

Comment: Is it possible to do the percentages in a calculated column to total the items for the quarter then create a percentage to display on my page by month and quarter?

Comment: No,we need to get this by javascript.